# Matter fields on spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

In *"The Large Scale Structure of Space and Time" by Hawking and Ellis* the following is stated:

> "There will be various fields on $M$, such as the electromagnetic field, the neutrino field, etc., which describe the matter content of space-time"

Here $M$ is meant to be a spacetime (i.e. a smooth $4$-dimensional manifold). From a mathematical perspective, how does one interpret "field" as quoted above. Are the authors saying that these matter fields (such as the electromagnetic field and the neutrino field) are *vector fields* on $M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a physicist, a “field” is any function over the manifold taking values in some vector space. Scalar fields are just real/complex functions on $M$, vector fields are just vector-valued functions over $M$, and spinor fields are spinor-valued functions over $M$. These fields are taken together with some action or stress tensor to couple them to the gravitational field.

Mathematically, a “field” is a section of some bundle $E$ over $M$, taken together with some least-action principle or stress tensor. A scalar field is a section of a line bundle, a vector field is a section of the (co)tangent bundle; spinor fields are sections of the “spin bundle”, and the gravitational field is a section of the (0,2) tensor bundle.

Answer (score 1):

No. The electromagnetic field is a vector field (as is the gluon field and those for the W and Z bosons) but the neutrino fields are *spinor* fields (as are those for the quarks, and for the electron,  muon, and tau). Finally the Higgs field is a *scalar* field.

In general, “field” here simply means “quantum field” without implying anything about which representation of the local Poincaré group it might transform under.